# On the property of a nonnegative stochastic process "attracted" near zero

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $\{X_k\}$ be a nonnegative stochastic process satisfying
$$E\left[ X_{k+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_k \right] \leq \rho X_k + c,$$
where $0 < \rho < 1, c>0$. Intuitively, the process is likely to be attracted to a region near zero due to the effect of $\rho$. We can construct a supermartingale $Y_k = \rho^{-k} \left( X_k - \frac{c}{1 - \rho} \right)$, based on which we can bound the tail probability $P\left( X_k \geq M \right)$ by applying Doob's maximal inequality to $\left\{ Y_k \right\}$. Now I wonder:

1. Has the process been studied in the literature? What is the term for it, if any? It seems like such a form should be common in the study of Lyapunov functions for stochastic dynamical systems.
2. Can we go a step further from the tail probability and bound the "mass" beyond the threshold, i.e., $E\left[ X_k \mathbb{1}_{\left\{ X_k \geq M \right\}} \right]$ for sufficiently large $M$?  Intuitively, the quantity should decay quickly as $k$ and $M$ increases because of the "attraction".